# Safe to remove hardware if hard disk is still active?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have ejected an external hard drive via the Windows 7 icon in the system tray. After ~3 seconds, Windows said

> Safe to remove hardware

However, it's now ~4 minutes after I did that and the hard disk is still making noise as if it were reading or writing. Since the external disk is not in an enclosure, I can also feel the movements when I touch it.

What is the hard disk doing? Can I really safely turn it off?

Observations and additional info:

- The drive letters are gone and the drive is no longer available in the system tray.
- The disk is a Seagate 8 TB drive. It is not exactly new, maybe 2 years old.
- The disk has likely more than 10.000.000 files on it.
- The external disk is an [inateck docking station](https://www.inateck.com/hard-drive-accessories/hdd-docking-station/two-bay-usb-3-0-hdd-docking-station/inateck-fd2002-usb-3-0-hdd-docking-station-dock-klonen-fur-2-5-3-5-zoll-sataiiiiii.html) for 2 disks. It has a clone functionality for cloning disks independently from a PC, but I did not press the clone button. (It's hard to do that accidentally anyway)

Comment: Is this a new disk?

Comment: @harrymc: not exactly new. Maybe 2 years old. But new in that sense that it's a 8TB drive

Comment: I would suggest leaving it on to do its stuff for some hours or a day, as some firmware versions may decide to do housekeeping. If it continues, then you may have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, but one way to make sure  it okay is to log off/ shut down. It’s only really risky if the drive is writing, which “ejecting” tells Windows to flush all pending write operations. If you log off,  it will not possibly be still writing if you do one of those 2 things.